# Using SimpleDateFormat in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying the following code,

```
    Calendar signupDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    signupDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    signupDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 01);
    signupDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 01);
    Date signupDateTime = signupDate.getTime();

    new Object[]{signupDateTime};
    Date date = (Date) params[0];
    String format = (String) params[1];
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String expDateStr = (String) sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("Expiration Date: "+expDateStr);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not execute DateToString function for Date:" + params[0] + " with Pattern:" + params[1], t);
    }
```

This program prints: Expiration Date: 2014-02-32

While debugging, i reached in into java.text.DateFormat class in Java API into the following function,

```
 public final String format(Date date)
 {
     return format(date, new StringBuffer(),
                  DontCareFieldPosition.INSTANCE).toString();
 }
```

Runtime value of date parameter for format function is: Fri Feb 01 17:58:30 PST 2013

But this function returns: 2014-02-32

I am not sure how does formatting converts 01 to 32.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Vijay Bhore

Comment: What's your format string?

Comment: What are the values of `params` and why are you casting the output of `SimpleDateFormat.format()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: yep, he only leaves out one of the most important bits of information.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feb 1st is the 32nd day of the year. Your [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is probably using `DD` instead of `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

This is dangerous:

```
signupDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 01);
```

Don't use magic numbers like this since you or the next coder to maintain this code might not know that months are 0 based, that this sets the month to February not January.

Better:

```
signupDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
```

or

```
signupDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
```

Whichever was desired.